# Totient function

Tags: number-theory

what is the number of integers $k$ smaller than $n$ such that $k$ is coprime to both $n - 1$ and $n?$

I thought about using  Totient function and denote that n and n-1 are coprimes

Comment: See [this OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A057475) (it uses $n$ and $n+1$ instead of $n$ and $n-1$). There isn't much information there, so my guess is that there isn't much that can be done, although that may just as well be a result of lack of research, or maybe more is known but the OEIS is just not up to date.

Comment: @Arthur I read your answer, why did you delete it?

Comment: @Tortugut Because it was wrong.

Comment: @Arthur What do you think about inclusion and exclusion?

Comment: If you find a good way to count the numbers that have a factor in common with both $n$ and $n+1$, then you have your answer there. I initially thought the answer was $0$, but a counterexample like $8$ and $9$ having $6$ in common made me realize I was wrong. (That sequence isn't even in the OEIS as far as I can see.)